# Build Ada with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, ada, gradlew

I'm having trouble building Ada with Gradle. I figured it shouldn't be too difficult since Ada is built using the GCC and Ada compiler, but I was very wrong. I've scoured all over the internet and the Gradle documentation but I haven't been able to find a solution.

This is my error when I run ./gradlew build, ./gradlew compileCalcExecutableCalcC, or ./gradlew calcExecutable (my Ada file is called calc.adb)

> Execution failed for task ':assemble'.
>    No buildable binaries found:
>       - executable 'calc:executable': No tool chain is available to build for platform 'linux_x86-64':
>           - Tool chain 'gnat' (GNU GCC): Could not determine GCC metadata: failed to execute gnatmake -dM -E -v -.
>           - Tool chain 'gnat_clang' (Clang): Could not determine Clang metadata: failed to execute gnatmake -dM -E -v -.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
model{
    toolChains{
        gnat(Gcc){ // Gradle doesn't have an Ada toolchain, so we're creating a custom toolchain
            target("linux_x86-64"){
                path '/usr/bin'
                cCompiler.executable = 'gnatmake'
                cCompiler.withArguments{ args ->
                    Collections.replaceAll(args, "CUSTOM", '-f', '-u',     '-c')
            } // end cCompiler.withArguments
        } // end target()
    } // end gnat
    gnat_clang(Clang){
         target("linux_x86-64") {
            path '/usr/bin'
            cCompiler.executable = 'gnatmake'
            cCompiler.withArguments{ args ->
                Collections.replaceAll(args, "CUSTOM", '-f', '-u', '-c')
            }
        } // end target
    } // end gnat_clang
} // end toolChains
components{
    calc(NativeExecutableSpec){
        binaries.all{
            cCompiler.args "-f", "-u", "-c", "calc.adb"
        } // end binaries.all

        sources{
            c.source.srcDirs = ['src/']
            c.source.includes = ['**/calc.adb']
        }
    } // end calc
} // end components
} // end model
```

My Gradle and Gradle Wrapper version is 4.7 and my Groovy version is 2.4.12

**Update:**

Gradle recognizes the new flags now. Here's the updated build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'c'
model{
    toolChains{
        gnat(Gcc){ // Gradle doesn't have an Ada toolchain, so we're creating a custom toolchain
            target("linux_x86-64"){
                path '/usr/bin'
                cCompiler.executable = 'gnatmake'
                cCompiler.withArguments{ args ->
                   Collections.replaceAll(args, "CUSTOM", "-dM -E -v -.")
            } // end cCompiler.withArguments
        } // end target()
    } // end gnat
} // end toolChains
components{
    calc(NativeExecutableSpec){
        sources{
            c.source.srcDirs = ['src/']
            c.source.includes = ['**/calc.adb']
        }
    } // end calc
} // end components
} // end model
```

Now Gradle is spouting out a new error and I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

> No tool chain is available to build for platform 'linux_x86-64':
>       - Tool chain 'gnat' (GNU GCC): Could not determine GCC metadata: failed to execute gnatmake -dM -E -v -.
>       - Tool chain 'gnat_clang' (Clang): Could not determine Clang metadata: failed to execute gnatmake -dM -E -v -.

Comment: Do you really need to use gradle with Ada? At least you may want to try gprbuild utility, even with gradle.

Comment: I've tried using gprbuild with gradle but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Does that exact gnatmake commandline work standalone?

Comment: (oh and there's no point to the gnat_Clang section until the DragonEgg project produces some resiults)

Comment: Here, `gnatmake -dM -E -v -. - hello.adb` gives "gnatmake: switch character cannot be followed by a blank
" then deleting that gives "Unrecognised command line option : -.". Deleting "-." works, so I think you need to find out why Gradle builds broken command lines, and stop it doing that.

Comment: I share your pain ... We have an _ye olde_ Ada build that inside a makefile -- It just calls  `gnatmake` standalone command.  The KISS approach.  I think it would be more straightforward to use an "**Ada plugin**"  with a _model_ for how Ada projects  work.  That's what I discern from the language plugins like: java plugin, cpp, kotlin plugin, groovy plugin, etc.  Something like the Kotlin [native plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.native) may be a structure you can build on.